# How to switch windows and verify tab using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my Travel affiliate site, i open 4 tabs every time.I write a test case where I switch window and do some operation.But I am finding the way where I can verify that my expected all windows are open and condition will be satisfied another wise I will return test case false.

This is my code where i switch window and do operation if boolean condition but i not getting any way that all tabs are open perfectly

```
for (String windows : wd.getWindowHandles()) {

    wd.switchTo().window(windows);

    Reporter.log(wd.getCurrentUrl());
    if (wd.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("https://www.airbnb.com")) {

        Reporter.log("Great Airbnb Leave Behind is Opening :" + wd.getCurrentUrl());
        Reporter.log("Airbnb &sharedid=3&iratid=9627& Passed on Parameter :"
                + wd.getCurrentUrl().contains("&sharedid=3&iratid=9627&"));
    }
    if (wd.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("http://local.summerrentals2017.com")) {

        Reporter.log("Main Site Listing Page :" + wd.getCurrentUrl());
    }
    if (wd.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("http://a.cdn.intentmedia.net/a1/exit_unit.html")) {

        Reporter.log("Intent media Is opend here is Opening :" + wd.getCurrentUrl());

    }
}
```

Suppose here http://local.summerrentals2017.com & http://a.cdn.intentmedia.net/a1/exit_unit.html if this two site open i can do some operation.but i want to make sure all two tabs open..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you mean, but... what about setting some kind of flag at the beginning?

```
int counter = 0;
Set<String> handles = wd.getWindowHandles();
for (String windows : handles) {

    wd.switchTo().window(windows);

    Reporter.log(wd.getCurrentUrl());
    if (wd.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("https://www.airbnb.com")) {
        counter++;
        Reporter.log("Great Airbnb Leave Behind is Opening :" + wd.getCurrentUrl());
        Reporter.log("Airbnb &sharedid=3&iratid=9627& Passed on Parameter :"
                + wd.getCurrentUrl().contains("&sharedid=3&iratid=9627&"));
    }
    if (wd.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("http://local.summerrentals2017.com")) {
        counter++;
        Reporter.log("Main Site Listing Page :" + wd.getCurrentUrl());
    }
    if (wd.getCurrentUrl().startsWith("http://a.cdn.intentmedia.net/a1/exit_unit.html")) {
        counter++;
        Reporter.log("Intent media Is opend here is Opening :" + wd.getCurrentUrl());

    }
}
[...]
if (counter == handles.size()) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I want to make sure all link are open

Comment: By `all` what do you mean? You have 3 `IFs` there. Is the number static?

Comment: Yes all the link are static

Comment: I want to make sure all my expected link are open